# How to use mathematical logic to solve this problem?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, logic-translation

Here is a very simple problem for children, and I wonder if we can use mathematical logic(like "propositional logic" or "first order predicate logic", or others) and an automatic solver? Which means: formalize the statement of the problem, enter the formalized statement into the automatic solver, get an answer

- There are 3 teachers, Mike, Jack and John.
- One teaches art, one teaches music, and one teaches writing.
- Mike is older than whom teach music.
- Jack is younger than whom teach art.
- John is older than whom teach art.

Question: What do the 3 teachers teach?

Comment: From statements $2$, $4$ and $5$, we get that :

(i)Jack and John both don't teach art. This shows Mike is the teacher of art. 

(ii)Ages of Jack and John are in the order : Jack $\lt$ person teaching art $\lt$ John. Thus ages of three of them are in the order Jack $\lt$ Mike $\lt$ John (using (i)).

Using statement $3$ in the given data, we get that Jack teaches Music. It follows that John teaches writing.

Comment: I wonder what is the difference between "solving manually in mind" and "solving by logic". Do you want to solve it by an automatic solver? Which means: formalize the statement of the problem, enter the formalized statement into the automatic solver, get an answer. Or something else?

Comment: @beroal Thank you so much, what you said is just what I want to express, but I can't do it in proper English. I just edited the question with your words, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can do this with formal logic.

The given information can be formalized as follows:

$$\forall x (x = mike \lor x = jack \lor x = john)$$

$$\exists x (Art(x) \land \forall y (Art(y) \rightarrow y=x))$$

$$\exists x (Music(x) \land \forall y (Music(y) \rightarrow y=x))$$

$$\exists x (Writing(x) \land \forall y (Writing(y) \rightarrow y=x))$$

$$\forall x (Music(x) \rightarrow Older(mike,x))$$

$$\forall x (Art(x) \rightarrow Younger(jack,x))$$

$$\forall x (Art(x) \rightarrow Older(john,x))$$

together with some further fundamental truths:

$$\forall x \neg Older(x,x)$$

$$\forall x \forall y \forall z ((Older(x,y) \land Older(y,z)) \rightarrow Older(x,z))$$

$$\forall x \forall y (Older(x,y) \leftrightarrow Younger(y,x))$$

Any decent automated prover will be able to infer the answer from this information.